# Removing An Element From XML File Java

Tags: java, xml, netbeans

I have a xml file that contains this:

```
<class>
<Video>Spiderman</Video>
<Video>Superman</Video>
</class>
```

I want to remove one of them based on what a user inputs.  What I have so far is

```
for (int x=0; x<videodatabase.size(); x++) {
            if (inputVideo.getText().contentEquals(videodatabase.get(x))) {
                try {
                    String filepath = "videodatabase.xml";
                    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                    Document doc = docBuilder.parse(filepath);

                    // I want to remove the <Video>name of the video</Video> from the xml here.

                    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
                    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
                    StreamResult result =  new StreamResult(new File(filepath));
                    transformer.transform(source, result);
                }    
                catch(ParserConfigurationException pce){
                    pce.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch(TransformerException tfe){
                    tfe.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch(IOException ioe){
                     ioe.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch(SAXException sae){
                    sae.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

As you can see the program check to see if the name of the video typed is in the array list called videodatabase.  If it is it opens the xml file and prepares to remove the video inputted.  However I am stuck here.  I want the xml file to look like:

```
<class>
<Video>Spiderman</Video>
</class>
```

Comment: There are several ways to manipulate xml in Java. As your are using TransformerFactory, apparently you want to use XSLT, so the real question is: "how to remove an element with XSLT". Btw, you should pass the XSLT template to the newInstance() call. Another way would be to use JAXB to create a java model of the xml, remote one element and than serialise it to xml again.

Comment: I disagree with @Peter. Using the `TransformerFactory` is the standard way to serialize a DOM document. This doesn't mean automatically one have to use XSLT. I think it is far more easier to remove one node with simple DOM manipulation than with XSLT.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the missing part using XPath:

```
// Get a XPath instance
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
// Find the Video element with text 'Superman'
Element supermanVideo = (Element) xpath.evaluate("/class/Video[. = 'Superman']", 
    doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
if(supermanVideo != null) {
  // Remove this element from the parent
  supermanVideo.getParentNode().removeChild(supermanVideo);
}
// Serialize the XML document ...
```

Comment: instead of using the literal Superman, can you use an Array<String>?  bonus points for updating answer...